# Eclipse does not show Genymotion emulator list

Tags: android, eclipse, genymotion

I have installed the Genymotion plugin for eclipse and I have properly configured eclipse to recognize the Genymotion emulator, which I have created, but when I right click the project name and goto:

```
Run As > Android Application
```

Eclipse states that I do not have any AVDs configured and it does not bring up the list of Genymotion emulators as it should. What could be the problem?

thanks.

Comment: I know this is likely a dumb question, but are you running a genymotion emulator when you try to run your app? Just gotta check :P

Comment: Can you check that the debug bridge is running and connected to the Genymotion virtual machine?  Not sure what platform you're on, but you can check from the command line with `adb devices`.

Comment: @ zgc7009: It's my understanding that you do not have to have the emulator running to open the android application with eclipse.  eclipse should show you the list of genymotion emulators that you have created when you right click on the project name and select Run As > Android Application.  To my knowledge this is the only way to run your apps in the genymotion emulator.

Comment: @Helix I don't think so Eclipse shows the android emulator list. The genymotion plugin shows the created genymotion emulators. You should have a running Genymotion device.

Comment: @RohanKandwal Agreed. Although I use the Genymotion plug-in with AndroidStudio, all the plug-in does is give you a more convenient way to start the Genymotion devices.  They have to be already running and connected to the debug bridge for AS to list them in the run dialog. I believe Eclipse works the same way.

Comment: @PaulRatazzi I will do some more research and try to follow your suggestion. I will provide an update if I am not able to bring up the list within eclipse. thanks.

Comment: Solved: I made a change in the genymotion settings with the "Android SDK" path under the "ADB" tab and browsed to the "android-sdk" folder.  I now run the emulator first via eclipse or through the genymotion application and then run the andoird application by right clicking on the app name and going to Run As > Android Application.  It now runs but it still does not bring up the list of emulators with in eclipse if I do not have the emulator running first, for that you need to change settings with adb. I am happy with this solution.

Comment: @Helix I too use Android Studio but no Genymotion plugin is installed. All you have to do is run Genymotion, start emulator, run the app. If Genymotion is not shown, then select the `show chooser dialog` from configuration or use `adb devices` and see if Genymotion is listed.

Comment: @Helix Good! You can post your answer as solution and then accept it to mark the question solved.

Answer (score 1):

Go to help -> install new software -> add this link: http://plugins.genymotion.com/eclipse and then follow the steps.

Answer (score 0):

Solved: I made a change in the genymotion settings with the "Android SDK" path under the "ADB" tab and browsed to the "android-sdk" folder.  I now run the emulator first via eclipse or through the genymotion application and then run the android application by right clicking on the app name and going to Run As > Android Application.  It now runs but it still does not bring up the list of emulators with in eclipse if I do not have the emulator running first, for that you need to change settings with adb. I am happy with this solution.

Comment: This bug has been fixed with the last monday's release: 2.3.1. It should not happen anymore.

Comment: @eyal-lezmy I am actually using 2.3.1 though.